# Why does the compiler stops the name lookup on overloads?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction

I just read this article:[Fun with C++ namespaces](http://pizer.wordpress.com/2008/10/22/fun-with-c-namespaces-sarcasm/)
Where the author shows that the compiler stops looking for overloads when encountering the first one, here by using namespaces.

```
namespace A
{
   void f(int x); // like our std::sqrt(double)
}

namespace B
{
   struct S {}; // user-defined type with associated namespace B

   void f(S);
   void f(int, int);

   void test1()
   {
      using namespace A; // using DIRECTIVE
      f(1);              // ERROR  namespace A is not considered because
                         //        B contains two overloads for 'f'
      f(1,2);            // OK     B::f(int,int)
      f(B::S());         // OK     B::f(S)
   }   

   void test2()
   {
      using A::f; // using DECLARATION
      f(1);       // OK     A::f(int)
      f(1,2);     // ERROR  A::f  hides  B::f(int,int)
      f(B::S());  // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }
}

namespace C
{
   void test3()
   {
      using namespace A; // using DIRECTIVE
      f(1);              // OK     A::f(int)
      f(B::S());         // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }   

   void test4()
   {
      using A::f; // using DECLARATION
      f(1);       // OK     A::f(int)
      f(B::S());  // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }
}
```

Why is the compiler supposed to stop?

EDIT #1: The question is indeed ment to be: Why does the standard says so?

Thanks for all the answers!

Comment: because the standard says so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> the compiler stops looking for overloads when encountering the first one

No, it doesn't stop *"when encountering the first one"* otherwise you couldn't find both `B::f(int,int)` and `B::f(S)`.

It finds all overloads in a given scope (not only the first one), but then doesn't look further in more distant scopes.

That's like all name lookup in C++, if you have a global variable called `var` and in some function you also have a local variable called `var`, using the name within the function will refer to the local variable. It's more useful that way, it's more likely that you meant to use the variable that is in declared nearby, as it's in related code.

If someone hands you a letter and tells you to give it to Fred, who is standing a few metres away wearing a badge that says "I am Fred", would you ignore him and go outside and keep looking for every other person in the world called Fred?

Comment: Good and easy to understand analogy. But me, as a novice programmer, actually expected from the compiler to do a complete lookup. Until I read the blog post. Is there a compiler option to spot such cases so that the compiler could warn me? Or better, whats the name of this behaviour so I can google it... (name lookup?)

Comment: @0x499602D2, no, I would say name lookup. Overload resolution generally refers to deciding which of several named functions is the best match, but you have to perform name lookup to find those functions first

Comment: It's sometimes said that a declaration of a name in an inner scope *shadows* the declaration in the outer scope

Answer (score 1):

using A::f hides all previous definitions of "f".

You can either use

```
   void test2()
   {      
      f(1,2);     // ERROR  A::f  hides  B::f(int,int)
      using A::f; // using DECLARATION
      f(1);       // OK     A::f(int)
      f(B::S());  // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }
```

or

```
   void test2()
   {
      using A::f; // using DECLARATION
      f(1);       // OK     A::f(int)
      using B::f;
      f(1,2);     // ERROR  A::f  hides  B::f(int,int)
      f(B::S());  // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }
```

Best practice is to call

```
   void test2()
   {
       A::f(1);       // OK     A::f(int)
       B::f(1,2);     // ERROR  A::f  hides  B::f(int,int)
       B::f(B::S());  // OK     B::f(S) due to ADL!
   }
```

It explicitly mention which function is used

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is: because the standard says so.  The reason
the standard says so is to make your programs more robust:
suppose you've written your class:

```
class MyClass : public SomeBase
{
private:
    void f( int );
    void g()
    {
        f( 'x' );
    }
};
```

As it stands, at the call site in `g`, the compiler will find
`MyClass::f(int)`, and only `MyClass::f(int)`.  Which is
probably what you want.  What you don't want is the compiler to
suddenly start finding `SomeBase::f(char)` if someone happens to
add it.  (So, at least, goes the rationale.)

And finally: the compiler *doesn't* always stop looking when it
finds a symbol.  There's ADL to take into account, for example.
And the rules are slightly different in templates, depending on
whether the symbol is dependent or not.

Comment: When `SomeBase` also got such a method, then I'd expect the compiler to choose the more specialized method -> `MyClass::f( int )`