# Why is the ADL not working when `using directive` is used?

Tags: c++

[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24384020/why-does-the-compiler-stops-the-name-lookup-on-overloads), but in this question it works, however, it fails in the following circumstance, why?

```
namespace A
{
  int k;
}
namespace B
{
  class test{};
  void k(const test&){/*do something*/}
}

int main()
{
  using namespace A;
  k(B::test());//compile error
}
```

**Error message is:** "'A::k' cannot be used as a function"  (gcc 6.3.0)

That is to say, the compiler does not try to do **ADL** and never find the `void k(const test&)` in `namespace B`

However, I think the **ADL should work in such situation** because the code above does not belong to the following circumstance:

quoted from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)

> First, the argument-dependent lookup is not considered if the lookup set produced by usual unqualified lookup contains any of the following:
>   1) a **declaration** of a class member
>   2) a **declaration** of a function at block scope (that's not a using-declaration)
>   3) any **declaration** that is not a function or a function template (e.g. a function object or another variable whose name conflicts with the name of the function that's being looked up)

To be more precise, here the `using namespace A` **does not introduce any declaration:**
quoted from [cppref](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace)

> Using-directive does not add any names to the declarative region in which it appears (unlike the using-declaration), and thus does not prevent identical names from being declared.

Comment: There isn't a declaration in `main()`, but there is one in namespace A, which is found by unqualified lookup with the help of the `using namespace A;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The name lookup for a function call has two parts:

- normal unqualified lookup
- ADL

According to N4659 [basic.lookup.argdep]/3, the normal unqualified lookup happens first; and then ADL stage does not go ahead if the normal unqualified lookup found:

> - a declaration of a class member, or
> - a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
> - a declaration that is neither a function nor a function template.

In your code the normal unqualified lookup does find `A::k` as discussed in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49312133/). So ADL does not happen for this code.

Answer (score 2):

> A using-directive specifies that the names in the nominated namespace can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after the using-directive. *During unqualified name lookup (6.4.1), the names appear as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace.*

So, unqualified name lookup will find A::k, that is the reason for the error.